# Cross Site Scripting issue

Tags: standardsetcontroller, selectoption, reflected-xss

I am getting XSS issue for the following statements in my code :

a. `lstDisplay.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));`

b. `lstDisplay.add(new SelectOption(selectOptionObj.getValue(),selectOptionObj.getLabel()));`

c. `standardSetCntrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Name FROM '+ strSelectedObject +' LIMIT 1'));`

What can be the possible reason for this.

Comment: Can you post error message?

Comment: We didn't get any error message. We just got the security scan report in which above lines are showing XSS issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is with this line:

```
standardSetCntrl = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Name FROM '+ strSelectedObject +' LIMIT 1'));
```

This variable `strSelectedObject` would be bound by Visualforce page. You should escape it as:

```
String.escapeSingleQuotes(strSelectedObject);
```

Look like:

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Name FROM '+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(strSelectedObject); +' LIMIT 1'));
```

Salesforce thinks that someone can hack this String.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What can be the reason for other two statements?

Comment: Other statements are fine. Only `c` is wrong.